# Given a int suppose 5, whose binary representation is 101, we need to flip the bit which will be 010, which will be 2

Tags: java

I am converting the given int to binary represention which is string, and then traversing the string and changing each char/bit in string and then converting back to required int.

Myquestion is, is there a mathematical or better way to do this?

Comment: You should look at bitwise operators in Java

Answer (score 0):

Using the bitwise operator `~` (not) you can do it without iteration. Example method:

```
public static int flipBits(int n) {
    return ~n;
}
```

You can also do it without a method, but for a general use using a method may be easier.

Comment: Careful as that flips non significant bits as well (0s on the left of original number), might not be the result asker is looking for.

Comment: And... what about the sign bit, and all the other bits between the sign bit and the very first '1' bit?

Comment: this gives me -6 as answer but required is 2

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got one more solution in which we find the maximum number that can be formed by digit's length bit, i.e for 5 `101' we can get 111 which is 7, so we subtract 7-5(given number) = 2, required solution